# Delete related object records using flow

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

is it possible to delete related object related i.e delete child records when parent record is deleted using flow and process builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot start process by porcess builder on record `delete`. It will start only when record `insert` or `update` happens.

You need to have a trigger for the same to handle deleted parent record ids and delete related child records.

Please upvote this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LlbtQAC